# How to Unschedule the report in salesforce

Tags: reporting

As per the salesforce Documentation, we can unschedule the report,But i cannot find the Unschedule the report option in salesforce

[image]

please anyone  guide me to unschedule option

Answer (score 1):

In classic UI you have to go to

> Setup->Jobs->ScheduledJobs

and then delete the report that was scheduled by you.

Src: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_monitoring_jobs.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.salesforce.com%2Fapex%2Fhtdoor%3Floc%3Dhelp%26target%3Ddata_monitoring_jobs.htm%26section%3DData%26language%3Den_US%26release%3D218.5%26instance%3DCS88&siteLang=en_US&type=5

Comment: You should probably mention something about Classic...

Comment: sure I will add.